# How would I make a model for my data and assign existing entity to new entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to programming and I have been into normalizing data and making a class diagram based on this normalized data. I seem to have trouble understanding how I would be working with this as I am trying to create an ASP.NET MVC application to work with this data.

This would be my class diagram:
[image]

Would this class diagram appear correct in the first place? Or should I make a relationship between Order and Stock? Or can there be multiple relationships (one going from stock class to order class and one going from stock class to products class)? Would I have to add StockId to the Order class (so that I can check if there is enough available of the product in the stock)?

How could my StockController class and a related Create view look like to assign a location to a product when adding new products to the Stock (so that the stock view would be updated)? I thought of adding new products in such StockController class aswell since I do not wish to add another view to display all products, as I want the Create view of the Stock class (thus using the Create method in the StockController) to do this job.

I would be making a model class specifically for Location and a controller with Enity Framework automatically generated views and CRUD operations to create a set of Locations and display an overview of this (how to generate this is not part of my question, but it's just to make the idea of my question a bit more clear).

I tried to let Entity Framework generate CRUD operations for the Stock class but this obviously would not work by default as I will not be inserting a new location, but actually assigning it to a (new) product. I wish to know how I can make assigning an existing location to a product, whilst creating a new product, possible in a Create method of a StockController class. I would also like to know how to make it possible to assign one or multiple locations in the Edit method. Could anyone give me an example of how I could achieve such? Am I correct to say that my model Stock class should contain a property which should contain a `List<Location> Locations`?

Edit: Please do not mind my typo's in the diagram.

Comment: Your diagram is not correct. A customer can have 0 or more, or 1 or more depending on your business requirement, orders. Right now it says a customer can have one order but an order can have many customers. Also, in most cases an order can have one or more products on it and a product can be on one or more orders; therefore, it will be a many to many relationship and you will need a bridge (other terms exists) in between. Your question is not one question but many questions and StackOverflow is not the best place for it. If you have a specific question then it is the perfect place. Try google

Comment: I thought that one customer can have multiple orders. I guess I should invert the line in my diagram concerning that. @CodingYoshi

Comment: Well it depends on the business requirements. In some organization, even if you have not placed an order, you are still a customer. In others, you must place one order to become a customer. In yet in some other organization it may be a different rule. In any case, your diagram is not correct.

Comment: Would that be the only part about the diagram being incorrect?

Comment: I mentioned 2 parts being incorrect. Those are the parts I can predict because of common knowledge of customer order entry applications. You have other concepts which I am not aware of. The important takeaway here is that it `ALL DEPENDS ON YOUR BUSINESS REQUIREMENTS`. Your diagram could be 100% correct if that is what the business operates as. Hard to say.